# Database Polling using RxScala

Tags: observable, rx-scala

TableEntriesI'm starting out with RxScala and I'm trying to come up with a polling mechanism that checks the database for every interval (say 20 seconds), to check if there was any change in some of the rows in the table.

```
object MyDatabaseService {

  def getAllEntries: List[MyTableEntries] = ???
}
```

I would need to start out with an Observable that will emit List[MyTableEntries]. So I started out with the following:

```
class MyDBObservable(service: MyDatabaseService, observer: Observer[Seq[MyTableEntries]]) extends Observable[Seq[MyTableEntries]] {

  val o = Observable.interval(10.seconds).map { _ => service.getAllTableEntries }
  o.subscribe(observer)
}
```

In my Observer that I pass in to the function, I have the onNext, onError and onCompleted implemented! There are a couple of questions however:

1. What happens if my database takes more than 30 seconds to respond
2. What happens if my database is completely down?

Is this a valid approach what I have done? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens if my database takes more than 30 seconds to respond

Assume the first `service.getAllTableEntries` needs 30 seconds, the second and the third `service.getAllTableEntries` need 1 seconds.

Then in your example, the first `service.getAllTableEntries` happens at 10 seconds, the second one happens at 40 seconds, the third one happens at 41 seconds.

Basically, the events won't be skipped because of the long-running actions. Instead, just delay the events.

> What happens if my database is completely down?

If so, I think `service.getAllTableEntries` will throw an exception, and you will receive it in `onError`.